# Express server sends 500 error code when doing post / put request with large string

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, put, body-parser

I am building small project when I use `nodejs` + `express` and `body-parser` package to manage my routes and data on the server side.
On the front end I have simple `react` app that has installed `tinyMCE` editor.
Problem is when I select image to insert to a document, editor makes it a `base64` blob and when I attempt to save changes including that base64 image (by doing PUT request to server) node spits error 500.
At the beginning I was thinking its a problem with application json headers as suggested in one of the git issue topics.

So I switched to

`"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`

Yet problem persists.

Then I tried with some small image `16x16` (previously it was `340x300`) and it worked...

So it means probably that POST had too much characters in the data section, but I thought limit is to `1.9GB`.

Here is some server code example:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

router.put("/:id", update);

const update = (req, res, next) => {
    documentController.update(req, res, next);
};

const update = async (req, res, next) => {
    const { name } = req.body;
    const document = await Document.findOne({ name });

    ...

    document
        .save()
        .then(document => {
            ...
        })
        .catch(err => next(err));
};
```

and front end request:

```
  request = async (url, method, data) => {
    try {
      let headers = {
        //"Content-Type": "application/json"
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
      };
      let config = {
        headers,
        method
      };
      if (data !== undefined) {
        //config["body"] = data;
        let query = "";
        data = JSON.parse(data);
        for (let key in data) {
          query +=
            encodeURIComponent(key) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(data[key]) + "&";
        }
        query = query.slice(0, -1);
        config["body"] = query;
      }
      let response = await fetch(url, config).catch(error =>
        console.log(error)
      );
      let json = await response.json();
      return json;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
```

Maybe some one can point me to whats wrong with PUT request when image is larger and how to solve it.

**EDIT**

yes as i suspected its a problem with large string, i checked error:

> message: 'request entity too large',
>   expected: 328465,
>   length: 328465,
>   limit: 102400,

**EDIT 2**

this is complete solution that solves the problem

```
app.use(
  bodyParser.urlencoded({
    limit: "50mb",
    extended: true,
    parameterLimit: 50000
  })
);
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: "50mb" }));
```

Comment: what errors appear in node's console when the browser encounters error 500?

Comment: yeah good that you asked, i updated my question with error log

Comment: I've updated my answer. have a look and see if that fixes your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [`multer`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer) node middleware. It will handle the upload using [streams](https://flaviocopes.com/nodejs-streams/#what-are-streams), instead of waiting for the whole file to be loaded in server's memory before saving it.

**Edit** (after seeing the comment with the error)

Try and increase the size limit your app accepts with:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '50mb'}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: '50mb', extended: true}));
```

Comment: the problem is, i am not uploading image, i cant have them as files on server, they must be base64 blobs inside document, due to later operations happening on that documents. So its not really a problem with image upload, its a problem with sending string to server that is probably too long.

Comment: i tried it, but it wasnt enough then i found that extra param is needed, so i added full solution at the and of my question, but you pointed me to the right direction, thank you